# How to extend or merge volumegroup in Centos?

Tags: linux, centos, lvm

```
[root@localhost ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
                   50G  2.1G   45G   5% /
tmpfs                 7.8G   12K  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda2             477M   67M  385M  15% /boot
/dev/sda1             200M  260K  200M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home
                  860G   72M  816G   1% /home
```

I have above configuration in my Centos. Now, I want to extend my /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root with /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home. Is it possible? Can I merge them together so that I only have /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root? Please help.